# Commit row by row in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have this code in my function with posgres:

```
with data_count as(
select
    *
from
    table_t as rrt
where
    rrt.cong_thuc = '' is false
order by
    "level",
    id)
update
    table_t rp
set
    tong = (
    select
        sum(tong)
    from
        table_t t
    where
        t.ma_chi_tieu = any(string_to_array(rp.cong_thuc, '+'))),
    eur =(
    select
        sum(eur)
    from
        table_t t
    where
        t.ma_chi_tieu = any(string_to_array(rp.cong_thuc, '+')))
from
    data_count t
where
    rp.id = t.id;
```

If one row have `level` >= 2, `cong_thuc` containt all `ma_chi_tieu` joined by `+` symbol, If row have `level` 1, `cong_thuc` is empty, 
I want to update `tong`, `eur` in all row have level 2,3,4,... by sum all row have `ma_chi_tieu` in other row containt in `cong_thuc`, but it's not working for once execute. I don't want to loop from 1 to max level. i'm understanding that this query don't update row by row.
My input is here

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ Ma_chi_tieu ║ cong_thuc ║ level ║ eur  ║ tong ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ R01         ║           ║     1 ║    5 ║    2 ║
║  2 ║ R02         ║           ║     1 ║    6 ║    3 ║
║  3 ║ R11         ║ R01+R02   ║     2 ║ 5000 ║ 6000 ║
║  4 ║ R04         ║           ║     1 ║    7 ║    6 ║
║  5 ║ R05         ║           ║     1 ║    8 ║    7 ║
║  6 ║ R12         ║ R04+R05   ║     2 ║ 1000 ║ 2000 ║
║  7 ║ R13         ║ R12+R11   ║     3 ║16000 ║18000 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Here is my expected output

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ Ma_chi_tieu ║ cong_thuc ║ level ║ eur ║ tong ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ R01         ║           ║     1 ║   5 ║    2 ║
║  2 ║ R02         ║           ║     1 ║   6 ║    3 ║
║  3 ║ R11         ║ R01+R02   ║     2 ║  11 ║    5 ║
║  4 ║ R04         ║           ║     1 ║   7 ║    6 ║
║  5 ║ R05         ║           ║     1 ║   8 ║    7 ║
║  6 ║ R12         ║ R04+R05   ║     2 ║  15 ║   13 ║
║  7 ║ R13         ║ R12+R11   ║     3 ║  26 ║   18 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═════╩══════╝
```

this is my output

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ Ma_chi_tieu ║ cong_thuc ║ level ║ eur  ║ tong ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ R01         ║           ║     1 ║    5 ║    2 ║
║  2 ║ R02         ║           ║     1 ║    6 ║    3 ║
║  3 ║ R11         ║ R01+R02   ║     2 ║   11 ║    5 ║
║  4 ║ R04         ║           ║     1 ║    7 ║    6 ║
║  5 ║ R05         ║           ║     1 ║    8 ║    7 ║
║  6 ║ R12         ║ R04+R05   ║     2 ║   15 ║   13 ║
║  7 ║ R13         ║ R12+R11   ║     3 ║ 6000 ║ 8000 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Am i thinking this is true? How do I update this query for once executed?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: i'm edited following your suggest